# Power Supply 9v

Tags: power-supply, transistors, circuit-analysis, analog, power-electronics

Hi i am building a power supply for a project and the specifications are to build my own voltage regulator. 
The power supply consists of converting 120V AC to 9V DC with 100mA of current and minimum of 50mV of ripple. 
I have met most of the requirements except the 100mA of current and i am not quite sure how to go about it i am beginner in electronics. I am using the schematic shown below as a simulation. The circuit with the inductor on the left is acting as a transformer since in this software that is how transformers are created.

With this current simulation i am only getting approximately 54mA of current output node is between R3 and R5. What would i need to change in the schematic below in order to increase it to at least 100mA?
[image: Circuit]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please modify your post to ask a specific question.

Comment: Your schematic makes no sense. Please clarify what parts are doing what function.

Comment: Your circuit as shown (12V Zener) will not regulate at 9V, and the output node is not shown. Looks unstable due to R3/C2.

Comment: just a guess... maybe reduce R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest design that is still very similar to your design would be something like the one on the left, here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ob7y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ form up a divider. Adjust the values per your need. But set things up so there is about \$10\:\text{mA}\$ through both of them. The zener I chose is the standard \$6.2\:\text{V}\$ variety because it is so common. The tempco is certainly positive at this voltage and should oppose the tempco of \$Q_2\$'s \$V_\text{BE}\$ by close to the right amount. However, a \$5.6\:\text{V}\$ might be a little better in that regard.

(Also, though not shown here, you might consider the idea of a capacitor across the zener.)

The right hand schematic is in case you decide you want 10X or more output current. You may require a better transformer, of course, and a similarly increased capacitance at the output of your bridge rectifier (\$10\:\text{mF}\$ instead of \$1000\:\mu\text{F}\$.)

Neither of these include a current limit or current foldback. That would require a few more parts. Here's something for \$100\:\text{mA}\$ with current foldback protection:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3XSNM.png)</sup>

That one can handle a short circuit at the output.